# Образование множественного числа

Tags: морфология

Как пишем во множественном числе словосочетание "Утреннее солнце"?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, "утреннее солнце" во множественном числе - не очень логичное и реальное словосочетание, хотя такой образ есть у Маяковского ("в сто сорок солнц закат пылал"), но если нужно поставить эту фразу во множественное число, то все - по правилу: утренние солнца

Comment: У Маяковского не совсем то. Там подразумевается "силой в сто сорок солнц". Аллюзия на тогдашнее использование "лампочка в сорок свечей", сейчас говорят "в сорок ватт".

Answer (score 1):

Я представила жёлтые одуванчики на лугу летним утром. Чем не **утренние солнца**? Одуванчики раскрылись. В переносном значении выражение вполне употребимо.

Comment: Да, это пойдет.

Answer (score 0):

Теоретически - да. Но насколько это необходимо практически?

Comment: Я о том же написал: зачем такое бессмысленное словосочетание?

Answer (score 0):

Это смотря где пишем.
Если в фантаcтическом рассказе "утро на планете в системе двойной звезды" то "утренние солнца". В остальных случаях - лучше никак. Контекст дайте, может разберемся.